# How can i do this in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have a datagridview which is binded on a table and i cannot display the data that i want exactly..i provide some figures that i make **(not code)** i hope you get the solution to my problem with the help of these:

[image]

above is the actual datagridview display and it is binded to sec_role_module

[image]

and here is the reference table which i called table sec_module

[image]

and here is the datagridview display that i want to come up.

i dont know how to do it..but i have the idea to use combobox and use valuemember and displaymember..but i want to do it by using textbox and not combobox.

please provide me some code..thanks alot experts!

Comment: finally i got it...thanks for viewing.

Comment: You should post what you did as an answer and accept it

Comment: You didn't define your problem very well. From what I assume you were getting at, you could also have used a view class with a property that displayed the field how you wanted and bound that directly to a textBoxColumn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my own question..i just use datagridviewcomboboxcolumn and change its displaystyle to none..so it is now view as a textbox that has a datamember. =)